# Rails caching model variables - how to "force reload"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm implementing a heap data structure in Rails, so I've got basically a binary tree, with nodes that have `id`, `name`, and `parent_id`.

I've noticed a really strange error when I try to "bubble up" one of my nodes. Here's what's up.

```
node = Item.find(266)
node.children.size
 => 0

node.swap_up
node.children.size
 => 0

node = Item.find(266)
node.children.size
 => 2
```

The behavior I'm expecting to see is that after I `swap_up` the `node`, it should have 2 children (as a result of bubbling up one level in the tree). But somehow the value of 0 "persists" until I "re-get" the node from ActiveRecord.

Here's the relevant definition from my `model/item.rb`

```
belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Item'
has_many :children, :class_name => 'Item', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
```

This is causing all kinds of insane behavior in my heap implementation. Is there any way I can ensure that a node's children are "updated" when methods are called that affect it? (Or that more accurately, that affect the parent_id of *other* nodes to start pointing to it?)

Any help you guys might have would be invaluable. Thanks!

Comment: Can you try to rewrite the scope `:children` with a lambda, for lazy loading? I don't know if it can help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a suggestion that may help.

This retrives item from db

```
node = Item.find(266)
node.children.size
 => 0
```

This uses cached item

```
node.swap_up
node.children.size
 => 0
```

I believe you can get rid of the cached copy and force it to go back to the db by doing this

```
node.swap_up
node.children(true).size
 # should get => 2
```

instead of having to query the db again.

Comment: Ah, this is great! I had never worked with resetting the ActiveRecord cache before. One wrinkle is that I was overwriting the `children` method to `return super.sort_by(blah)` and this was triggering a `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` exception. Is there a way that I can both customize the method _and_ have it accept the `(true)` argument?

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Im not sure about the question in the comment but if you post another question with some more detail, I'm sure you'll get some suggestions from others and I will take a look at it.